# What do i have to do to avoid this Exception?

Tags: json, api, user-interface, openai-api

this is the part of the code that is giving me problems:

```
    output = completetions.choices[0].text.strip()
    print(output)
    trivia = json.loads(output)
    return json.dumps(trivia, indent=4)
```

And this is the error am getting:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Gabo\Documents\Taller de programación\Proyecto programado.py", line 68, in start_game
    trivia = self.generate_trivia(topic, num_questions, language)
  File "C:\Users\Gabo\Documents\Taller de programación\Proyecto programado.py", line 59, in generate_trivia
    trivia = json.loads(output)
  File "C:\Users\Gabo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Gabo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Haven't tried much since this is my first time working with json stuff, please help haha

Comment: The problem isn't with the code, it's with the data in `output`. Can you [edit] your question to show what's in `output`?